# How to run function after a component became visible in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I want to load datas only if the user see the specific component which load the datas. So don't load before the component is visible.

I have this template:

```html
<button (click)="showMyCompontente()">Click me</button>
<app-other-component *ngIf="show"></app-other-component>
```

With this TypeScript code:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  show = false;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  showMyCompontente() {
    this.show = !this.show;
  }
}
```

And the point is here:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-other-component',
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    // needs to load datas only if the user see the component
  }
}
```

How to achive in the `OtherComponent` to start the `this.load()` only if the component is visible to the user? I want to reload datas again if the user hide the component and show it agian.

I need a solution inside the component to detect itself is became visible or disappear. That's because I have many compontents, calling eachothers in many variations.

Which Angular lifecycle hooks fires only when the user shows the component?

Comment: Did you try `ngAfterViewInit()` ? Else, you'd have to provide more code to clarify how you show and hide the component.

Comment: you must be looking for AfterViewInit

Comment: @Kokodoko yes, but it run too when the parent component is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try:

- Adding an input property with type of boolean to `OtherComponent` component.
- Passing value of `show` to the input property, then inside the `OtherComponent` component, use `ngOnChanges` to detect any change in the input property and call `load()` accordingly.